# Join mysql table on itself by distinct values in one column

Tags: mysql, sql

My mysql table *dummy* looks like this:

| name | number | some_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| A | 2 | 4 |
| A | 3 | 7 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| C | 3 | 5 |
| C | 4 | 4 |
| ... | ... | ... |

And i want to join the table on itself by each distinct **name** value where the **number** equals and then select only **some_value** and **number** as index once. I know sound a bit messy so here would be the example from above:

| number | A.some_value | B.some_value | C.some_value | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | null | ... |
| 2 | 4 | null | null | ... |
| 3 | 7 | null | 5 | ... |
| 4 | null | null | 4 | ... |

I would be very grateful if someone could help me and tell me the query to do that.

Comment: What's the criteria for whether the value is in A, B, or C?

Comment: For a start, this will need to be a LEFT JOIN to get null values.

Comment: I the table at the beginning there is a column **name** with A,B,C, .. that defines if a the value of **some_value** is in the column A.some_value, B.some_value, ... . So to speak the **name** column at the beginning defines the position on the x-axis and the **number** column on the y-axis in the resulting table.

Comment: Oh, then this is just a pivot of the table.